# Re-route hypertext link clicks to external URLs to another browser than the Electron app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, webview, electron

I have an Electron `BrowserWindow`, which contains UI elements and a `BrowserView` created with:

```
bv = createBrowserView('https://example.com');
...
browserWindow.setBrowserView(bv);
```

How to limit this [BrowserView](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view) to URLs of the form `***.example.com/***`, i.e. to stay on the domain `example.com`?

More precisely, if the user clicks on a hypertext link going out of this domain, it should be opened in an external application, such as the system's default browser, but not in the Electron app.

**How to do this with Electron BrowserView?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
bv.webContents.on('will-navigate', (event, url) => {
    console.log('will-navigate', url);
    if (condition_on_the_url) {
        shell.openExternal(url);  // length limit on Windows: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellopenexternalurl-options
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Note: the event `new-window` is also useful when the user clicks on a link with `target="_blank"`.